# Scraping data straight to Cassandra database

Tags: python, database, cassandra, scrapy, pycassa

Can anyone help me with Cassandra database? Actually, I want to
through the scraped data directly to  Cassandra. Currently, I am using scrapy for parsing data from different websites.

Thanks-in advance.

ssich

Answer (score 2):

In Scrapy, once you have scraped the data you can run it through an item pipeline to store it.

The documentation is easy to understand: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Just use the python driver for Cassandra within you custom item pipeline to store the results.

---

**Edit:** Updated the dead link with working one.